# iis10 centralized certificate store gives PR_CONNECT_RESET_ERROR on wildcard certificate on domain root

Tags: windows, iis, certificate, pfx

Good evening,
i have a multisite iis configured with ccs (centralized certificate store).
i'm trying to handle [www.contoso.com](http://www.contoso.com) & contoso.com with a wildcard certifcate named _.contoso.com

[www.contoso.com](http://www.contoso.com) is working but contoso.com gives  secure connection failed PR_CONNECT_RESET_ERROR .

the bindings http & https for www & contoso.com are made on the same website definition

details of certificate is as follow :
i can see in Centralized certificate my certificate _.contoso.com.pfx  and is valid

`Subject  :  CN = *.contoso.com SAN : DNS Name = *.contoso.com      DNS Name = contoso.com`

what could be wrong ?

Thanks for your time

if i duplicate the file _.contoso.com.pfx into contoso.com.pfx the site works.
but the wildcard is supposed to handle contoso.com aswell.

netsh http show sslcert

`Central Certificate Store    : 443`

Comment: I don't think Microsoft designed it the way you wanted. Since at site binding level a wildcard binding of `*.contoso.com` won't serve `contoso.com` (you do need an extra site binding for `contoso.com`), I guess when CCS resolves the certificates it follows the same logic that `contoso.com` does not belong to `*.contoso.com`. Like you found out, you just need to copy `_.contoso.com.pfx` to `contoso.com.pfx`.

Answer (score 0):

You are right to try. Copying the file does the trick.

According to the [File Naming Convention](https://serverfault.com/questions/622431/multiple-wildcard-certificates-on-one-iis-site)(The official doc already explains a lot), IIS will match the domain name according to the subject name. In CCS work, the subject name _.contoso.com cannot be matched to contoso.com. You can also refer to [this answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/622431/multiple-wildcard-certificates-on-one-iis-site) for a detailed explanation.